# Trigger stopped behaving as expected after MariaDB upgrade (from 10.1 to 10.4.6)

Tags: mysql, triggers, mariadb

I'm having trouble with one of my BEFORE INSERT trigger since i've upgraded to MariaDB 10.4.6 .

The trigger is defined as follow (removing the useless part)

```
 CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bins_stock`
 BEFORE INSERT ON `stock`
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN  

DECLARE maxprice DOUBLE DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE errormsg VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';

select  MAX(price)  into maxprice 
FROM view_articles
where view_articles.id_ref = NEW.id_ref;

IF (maxprice is null) THEN

  SET errormsg = CONCAT("INSERT ERROR : missing line in view_articles [art ref :  ",  NEW.id_ref ,  "]");

  SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = errormsg; 

END IF;

END
```

When inserting into the table "stock", i'll get my custom error even when i should not , with for example the message "INSERT ERROR : missing line in view_articles [art ref : 11757]"

The query :

```
select  MAX(price)  
    FROM view_articles
    where view_articles.id_ref = 11757;
```

Does not return null, so I shouldn't get this error triggered.

What i've tested so far :

- the value of "maxprice " in the trigger is effectively NULL (so it's not a problem with the if clause).
- if I modify the trigger to put 11757 in place of NEW.id_ref in the select query, maxprice isn't NULL.
- if I create a table "table_articles" similar to my view "view_articles", and  do an INSERT INTO  table_articles SELECT * FROM
  view_articles, then modify my trigger to use the table instead of the
  view, maxprice isn't null either.

Additional infos :

Sql mode  is set to 'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION' .
The user that has created the view, the table, the trigger, and that is used to insert into the table is the same, and has "grant all privileges on *.* ".
Tested with mariadb 10.4.6 (upgrade from 10.1 following upgrade instructions page) on debian 9, and a fresh install of same version on a windows machine, with the db loaded from a dump.

EDIT with more infos , tests & workaround : 
view_articles is defined (simplified) as follow :

```
CREATE VIEW view_articles  AS 
 SELECT articles2.id_ref as id_ref, articles2.pricing as price
  from articles2 
 UNION 
SELECT articles.id_article as id_ref, articles.price as price 
  from articles
```

If I used this statement directly in the trigger in place of the view,  I still have the same problem,  but this works :

```
IF(new.id_ref <0) THEN 
 select MAX(articles2.pricing) INTO maxprix    
      from articles2  WHERE articles2.id_ref =  new.id_ref ;
ELSE 
 select MAX(articles.price) INTO maxprix 
 from articles WHERE articles.id_article = new.id_ref ;
END IF;
```

So, is it now forbidden to use a view with an UNION clause in a trigger ? Or is this a bug ?

I'm not really satisfied with my workaround,  because someday I may have negative Ids in "articles" table and positive ones in "articles2", even if it's not the case for now. So I'm still welcoming more elegant solutions.

Comment: And if i replace "view_articles.id_ref = NEW.id_ref;"  by  "view_articles.id_ref  <> NEW.id_ref;"  then I get a value in maxprice. Not the one I want,  but it proves that the trigger can read from the view, it just fail on the "equal" part of the condition ... but why is still a mystery to me ( id_ref  is of type INT(11) )

Comment: Have you checked NEW.id_ref value in trigger? Is it supplied or auto increment? NVM, it is in error message so it is supplied.

Comment: @fifonik Yes , the value of NEW.id_ref is returned correctly in my custom error message, and it is not auto increment.  Also it works when i use it toward a table rather than toward my view.

Comment: Do the view_articles use the stock table? Does it work get not null you do not use aggregate function (`SELECT price FROM view_articles WHERE ... LIMIT 1`) ?

Comment: @fifonik I added details in the description. The view doesn't use "stock" table.  And changing MAX (  )  for    LIMIT 1  doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: I tried to do the same on my madiadb 10.1 & mysql 5.7 and everything works as it should (I used union in view). I'd recommend you to try to re-produce the issue with simple case: create 2 tables, 1 view, 1 trigger and check. If the issue still here, file the SQL script as bug report. BTW, what are the types of articles2.id_ref & articles.id_article?

Comment: If your articles2.id_ref in INT UNSIGNED but articles.id_article is INT (SIGNED) with negative values, the view will lost the articles.id_article as in UNION the first mentioned table is used to determine types. You can try to use `CAST(articles2.id_ref AS SIGNED) AS id_ref` in view to avoid this.

Comment: @fifonik for articles2 the column is defined as  `id_ref` int(11) NOT NULL , in articles it's `id_article` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT .

Comment: Try this: change from `NEW.id_ref` to `OLD.id_ref`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug affecting versions 10.2, 10.3 and 10.4 of MariaDB.  Have to workaround it until bug is fixed.
MariaDB bug tracker link : https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19975

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```mysql
MariaDB [(none)]> USE `_`;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+----------------+
| VERSION()      |
+----------------+
| 10.4.6-MariaDB |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT @@global.sql_mode, @@session.sql_mode\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
 @@global.sql_mode: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
@@session.sql_mode: STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `view_articles`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `articles`, `stock`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock`(
    ->   `id_ref` INT NOT NULL
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `articles`(
    ->   `id_article` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ->   `price` NUMERIC(10, 2)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE VIEW `view_articles`  AS
    -> SELECT `articles`.`id_article` `id_ref`, `articles`.`price`
    -> FROM `articles`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER //

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TRIGGER `trg_bins_stock` BEFORE INSERT ON `stock`
    -> FOR EACH ROW
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `maxprice` NUMERIC(10, 2) DEFAULT NULL;
    ->   DECLARE `errormsg` VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT '';
    -> 
    ->   SELECT MAX(`price`) INTO `maxprice`
    ->   FROM `view_articles`
    ->   WHERE `view_articles`.`id_ref` = NEW.`id_ref`;
    -> 
    ->   IF (`maxprice` IS NULL) THEN
    ->     SET `errormsg` := CONCAT('INSERT ERROR: missing line in view_articles [art ref: ',  NEW.`id_ref` ,  ']');
    ->     SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = `errormsg`; 
    ->   END IF;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DELIMITER ;

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `articles`
    -> VALUES (11757, 2000);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT `id_article`, `price`
    -> FROM `articles`;
+------------+---------+
| id_article | price   |
+------------+---------+
|      11757 | 2000.00 |
+------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `stock`
    -> VALUES (11757);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT `id_ref`
    -> FROM `stock`;
+--------+
| id_ref |
+--------+
|  11757 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `stock`
    -> VALUES (1);
ERROR 1644 (45000): INSERT ERROR: missing line in view_articles [art ref: 1]
```

Comment: you are missing the UNION  clause on your view.  Bug has been confirmed by MariaDB team.